# The modification of key bindings in eclipse does not work

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

May I ask a question about the modification of key bindings in Eclipse? I get it configured in Eclipse but it doesn't work, I want the code blocks to be automatically surrounded with try/catch statements when the key ‘ctrl+9’ is input, but unfortunately it does not work, it seems nothing is happenning. The version of Eclipse I am working on is Mars.1 Release (4.5.1) Build id: 20150924-1200. Please see the snapshot below, thanks a lot!

[image: Please click here for the snapshot]

Comment: anything happens at all or nothing?

Comment: see if this helps [Link](https://techblog.ralph-schuster.eu/2013/10/13/eclipsee4-problem-with-key-bindings/comment-page-1/)

Comment: nothing happens when I try to input the keys

Comment: did you selected few java statements below pressing this key?

Comment: @ChandrayyaGK Yes, I did